# Java Swing Animation Stutters on 60hz Monitor

Tags: java, swing, animation

I've been working on a 2D game in Swing and accidently came across an issue. Normally, when I run my code and test the game, the game window is on my 240hz monitor and everything is nice and smooth, however, when I move the window to my 60hz monitor I notice that the animation for the "side-scrolling" obstacles aren't smooth at all. They're moving across the screen, but they're micro-stuttering the whole way across, and at regular intervals I've noticed.

I've tried using a thread instead of a timer and although the micro-stutters are reduced at lot, specifically when I set the delay to 16, they do still occur about every 1 second.

I'm not really sure what to do at this point, so any advice would be much appreciated!

Here are the relevant classes:

```
package dinoRun;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

```
package dinoRun;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    static GamePanel panel;

    Window() {
        panel = new GamePanel();

        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle("Dino Run");
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
package dinoRun;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class GamePanel extends Renderer implements ActionListener {

    final int WIDTH = 1280, HEIGHT = 720;
    Rectangle dino;
    ArrayList<Rectangle> cactii;

    GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        dino = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 20, HEIGHT / 2, 100, 100);
        cactii = new ArrayList<>();
        addCactus();
        Timer timer = new Timer(1, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    void paintDino(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(dino.x, dino.y, dino.width, dino.height);
    }

    void addCactus() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int space = rand.nextInt(64) * 10;
        cactii.add(new Rectangle(space + WIDTH * (cactii.size() + 1), HEIGHT / 2, 30, 100));
    }

    void paintCactus(Graphics g, Rectangle cactus) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(cactus.x, cactus.y, cactus.width, cactus.height);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    void repaint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paintDino(g);
        g.drawLine(0, HEIGHT / 2 + 100, WIDTH, HEIGHT / 2 + 100);
        for (int i = 0; i < cactii.size(); i++){
            if (cactii.get(i).getX() + cactii.get(i).getWidth() != 0) {
                paintCactus(g, cactii.get(i));
                cactii.get(i).translate(-10, 0);
            } else {
                cactii.remove(cactii.get(i));
                i--;
            }
        }
        addCactus();
    }
}
```

```
package dinoRun;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Renderer extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Window.panel.repaint(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, at 60hz, one might consider using a timing of something like `Timer timer = new Timer(16, this);` instead, but that could just one of any number of "small" issues

Comment: Movements in games should not be done in fixed intervals as this might lead to all kinds of weird behavior which would depend on the enviroment, e.g. your hardware. Try to calculate the "length" of each individual frame instead and use it along with some movement speed to calculate the next translation amount. You can still try to get to a somewhat fixed frame length in your main loop but the animations shouldn't know about that.

Comment: Btw, I would also split drawing and game update logic into separate threads. Right now your animations/game update depend on the UI update process which might be influenced by a couple of things, e.g. when the framework "decides" to do a repaint, how fast events are being processed etc.

Comment: One more observation: checks like `dino.getY() == (double)HEIGHT / 2` might not give you the results you want. Due to precision issue, rounding and other calculation artifacts you might never get the _exact_ same value. Instead try to calculate whether the dino is _close enough_, i.e. `Math.abs(dino.getY() - (HEIGHT/2.0)) < epsilon` where `epsilon` is the distance you'd consider "close enough" (e.g. 0.001).

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, using a delay a 16 reduces the stuttering, but doesn't completely eliminate them, even when using a thread. I'm thinking there's another issue that could also be causing the stuttering.

Comment: @Thomas I see. So instead of having the obstacles move at a constant 10 pixels to left, I should calculate the time or length of the frame and multiply it by some integer, say 10, to get the obstacles translation? Throughout the entire animation, the obstacle would have the same "velocity", which should remove or reduce the stuttering? Also, I see the issue with having the game logic in the repaint() method. Would the actionPerformed() method be a more suitable place to have the game logic?

Comment: @Kleopatra Sorry, I've updated the code I attached in my question and I hope it's a minimal reproducible example now. Also, when you say, "don't use static scope," do you mean the GamePanel that's created in the Window class?

Comment: Yes, the obstacles should have a "velocity" which is used to calculate the translation. This should remove stuttering unless you have a bad or highly volatile framerate. The logic should not go into `actionPerformed()` as this still would be on the UI's event dispatch thread. However, `actionPerformed()` and methods like this (e.g. those of `MouseListener`, `KeyListener` etc.) should set state which the separate logic thread also accesses.

Comment: @Thomas Ah I see. So the game logic should run on its own, separate thread. I'll try that out. Thanks for the help!